# i wish to make a cooldown within a on_raw_reaction for a certain function

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

since I can't use a cooldown decorator, i wanna check when the last message in the channel was sent since that is the last time it was used, and then
if the time is within 16 hours of the last function time, then you cant do the function again, if it is past 16 hours then you cant do the command again

ive tried the below code and i get issues so now im just straight out asking for help

```
          `` if charmnorm in member.roles:
                   print("right role")
                   if female in member.roles:
                       print("female role")
                       async for message in femchan.history(limit=3000):
                           print("works")
                           limittime = datetime.timedelta(hours=16)
                           createdate = message.created_at.date()
                           timenow = datetime.datetime.now().hour
                           sub = createdate.hour + limittime
                           print(f"createdate is {createdate}")
                           print(sub)
                           print(timenow)
                           print(limittime)

                           if f"{user.id}" in message.embeds[0].title:
                               limittime = datetime.timedelta(hour=16)
                               createdate = message.created_at
                               timenow = datetime.datetime.now().hour
                               sub = createdate.hour + limittime
                               print(f"createdate is {createdate}")
                               print(sub)    
                               print(timenow)
                               print(limittime)

                               if sub >= timenow:
                                   await user.send("Beginning Bump Now!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a database isn't a bad idea for this. You can store the UTC time for when the command was invoked last using `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` and then save that value with the channel ID as they key (since the command is channel specific).

You can then add an `if` condition to check if the difference between the UTC time of the command being invoked now and the value saved in the database has the required 16 hour difference.

Happy coding!